# Help is Depressed, It's Been Looking a Bit Down

Tags: bug, top-bar

The new topbar is decidedly awesome. It is like a top hat, only in bar form.

But it's got its hidden issues. The 'help' link looks a bit down because it is horribly misaligned:

[image: misalignment in the top bar]

The review seems to be aligned with your rep/badge numbers and the Stack Exchange logo in the top left. help and search seem to be on a different level, aligned against the rest of the top bar.

I'm all for standing out, but these several pixels are just taking it too far.

Comment: I actually don't have this problem, which is odd. Oh well.

Comment: @Emracool Are you using Firefox?

Comment: I searched so many times for a duplicate I assumed must exist, but they didn't include the word review so I missed it (help is likely the worst keyword to search for ever).

Comment: @Jona Makes sense. Ha! Chrome wins again!

Comment: @Emracool ... that's not how it works XD It doesn't count when it's _designed for_ Chrome.